# FFT (inverse M) = IFFT (M)

Tags: linear-algebra, signal-processing

Just to feed my curiosity, Is the following statement true:
FFT (inverse M) = IFFT (M)

Where FFT is the fourier transform, IFFT its inverse, and M a square matrix of any kind (made of natural integers).

Thanks,

Comment: Not at all. See the [FFT matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFT_matrix)

Answer (score 0):

It is not true at all. why did you think that it could be in the first place? here is a counterexample from Matlab:

fft([1 1; 2 1])

ans =

```
 3     2
 -1     0
```

ifft([1 1; 2 1]^-1)

ans =

```
0.5000         0
-1.5000    1.0000
```

Comment: Now what is true is that $(W M^{-1})^{-1} = M W^* = (W M^*)^*$ where $W$ is the FFT matrix or any unitary matrix